# Hibernate automatic read for auto increment non primary key column

Tags: hibernate

I have a non PK auto increment column in DB table which I have mepped through

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "unique_id");
```

But when I save this entity, this value doesn't get updated automatically on the Entity object because its not the @Id of the table. I had to manually do a session.flush() and session.load().
Is it possible to get the generated value in just one query as it happens for auto incr PK column wherein the JDBC returns the generated value in the result of session.save() itself.

Comment: i am facing same issue did you found the sollution?